# What is the meaning of "cross down"?

Tags: expressions

While translating a text I came across the expression: "cross down". The whole line (It's a play) is: "Beautiful. Cross down." And expresses kind of approval. Do you know the phrase? does it come from sporsts? Like "one point" or something alike? I cannot find it on the net.

Comment: Please link to the play and indicate where this line occurs. Meaning is often shown by more than a single line.

Comment: Is the person being spoken to holding a cross that they need to put down? Or do they have a list of words that includes "down" and they need to cross it out?

Comment: Cannot find such in any registries.

Answer (score 9):

This appears to be from [*Venus in Fur*](https://books.google.com/books?id=blh-AgAAQBAJ&pg=PT78&dq=%22Beautiful.+Cross+down.%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi2hprmvPzfAhXtm-AKHQVIBiUQ6AEIKjAA#v=onepage&q=%22Beautiful.%20Cross%20down.%22&f=false), by David Ives. The character speaking, Vanda, is directing her fellow-actor Thomas. *Beautiful* is a comment on his delivery of the preceding line; *cross down* in theatrical jargon is a direction to move ("cross") downstage = toward the audience.

Similarly, *up* would mean upstage = away from the audience, and *right* and *left* would mean stage right/stage left = to the right or left side of the stage from the actor's perspective.

Comment: Yes, thank you very much. I am consulting other theatrical expressions with an actor. Nevertheless, this one was unknown to them.

Comment: @Christina That's very odd if your consultant is a stage actor; the expression has been standard in the Anglo-American theatre for generations.

Comment: He is an English speaking actor, not a native one. Giving the references for the language I am translating to. For example in English it is "stage left", but during rehearsals we use "director's left" and similar cases.

Comment: Wouldn't the ‘cross’ indicate that the actor should move sideways (left or right) as well as downstage — i.e. moving diagonally?  But yes, this does seem like theatrical jargon that most non-actors probably wouldn't know.

Comment: @gidds No. Any movement is a "cross". "Cross down" describes the direction: "move downstage of your current position". A more complex direction would ordinarily name the destination (eg "Cross up right/down right center") but with a distance describes the direction: "Cross three steps down right". Note that in most modern stagings directions of this sort will be modified by reference to props: "Move down of *or* below the sofa".

Comment: @Christina This is why it's important to show *exactly* how things appear in your question. "Cross down" would have been separated from spoken dialogue in some way (different type, different line perhaps, maybe it was against the right margin) and that needs to be included in your question. It's relevant information.

Comment: @AndrewLeach  Quite so; but in this case, no: "Cross down" is a direction by the character, an actor, spoken to another actor during rehearsal :}.

Comment: @StoneyB Is it? That seems very odd. Which is precisely why it should appear in the question in the exact form of the script and in context. And perhaps the answer should give a link?

Comment: @AndrewLeach As you wish.